# Alternative or a better method to use pytorch in dockerfilee

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, dockerfile

My team is building a docker image that uses pytorch. When I am installing pytorch in the conda env, the image size shoots up in GB(s). The current image size is 5GB.

It is not possible to push such huge docker images to deployment as it will take too much time and will be unproductive. What are alternatives to this? Or how to optimize the image size?

This is my current dockerfile:

```
FROM python:slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt -qq update \
    && apt -y install wget ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget -q https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda3 \
    && rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && cp /opt/miniconda3/condabin/conda /bin/conda

RUN conda env create -f .condarc.yaml

CMD [ "conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0", "python3", "app.py"]
```

.condarc.yaml:

```yaml
name: myenv
dependencies:
  - cudatoolkit=10.2
prefix: /opt/miniconda
channel:
  - pytorch
```

requirements.txt

```
opencv-python
torch
torchgeometry
torchvision
```

Comment: PyTorch is [on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/torch/) and you should be able to install it without using Conda.  Installing it from a wheel should be fairly lightweight.  This also avoids the Docker-related troubles Conda brings (adding a line to `.bashrc` does nothing).  Does including `torch` in your `requirements.txt` file and skipping the Conda sequence entirely make things smaller?

Comment: Thanks for the input!! I have made the changes and I still find the size to be the same (5.88GB).

Comment: As I have understood from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch/tags) official developers of `pytorch` are also getting around several GBs for GPU-support full-featured image.

Comment: I understand that. I just had a tiny hope that I might be wrong and there would be a better alternative. Thanks though!!